# How to rotate a triangle without rotating the entire canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, html5-canvas

I'm new to working with `<canvas>` and terrible at maths. I'm drawing a simple equilateral triangle on my canvas with this function that has borrowed code from somebody else (don't hate me):

```
drawTriangle(PosX, PosY, SideLength, Orientation) {
    context.beginPath();

    var sides = 3;

    var a = ((Math.PI * 2) / sides);

    context.moveTo(PosX + SideLength, PosY);

    for (var i = 1; i < sides + 1; i++) {
        context.lineTo(PosX + SideLength * Math.cos(a*i), PosY + SideLength * Math.sin(a*i));
    }

    context.closePath();

    return true;
}
```

The function would only know the centre co-ordinates of the triangle and the orientation to point it at, nothing else.

It currently draws the triangle successfully but "points" east.

How do I rotate the triangle using the `Orientation` parameter (degrees) without rotating the entire canvas like other answers suggest?

Comment: If you rotate the canvas, then draw the triangle, then rotate the canvas *back*, won't that achieve your desired result and allow you to go on with further drawing? (You're not talking about rotating an existing triangle that was drawn previously, are you?)

Comment: The triangle is drawn every frame with the rest of the canvas that contains other shapes if that helps.

Comment: Right, so why is rotating the canvas, drawing the shape, then rotating back a problem? It's what the working solution below seems to do. (Not that this is the *only* possible solution, but if it's simple and it works...)

Comment: I'm trying it out now. :)

Comment: So his solution works but it's not actually an answer to my question about not rotating the canvas. Should I mark it as accepted anyway?

Comment: @Jared no there are many other ways to do it

Answer (score 7):

Here's a function that draws any regular polygon and a specified angle:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var sideCount=3;
var size=40;
var centerX=50;
var centerY=50;
var strokeWidth=4;
var strokeColor='purple';
var fillColor='skyblue';
var rotationDegrees=0;
var rotationIncrement=1;
var nextTime=0;
var delay=1000/60*1;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
    if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(animate);return;}
    nextTime=time+delay;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    drawPolygon(centerX,centerY,sideCount,size,strokeWidth,strokeColor,fillColor,rotationDegrees);
    rotationDegrees+=rotationIncrement;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function drawPolygon(centerX,centerY,sideCount,size,strokeWidth,strokeColor,fillColor,rotationDegrees){
    var radians=rotationDegrees*Math.PI/180;
    ctx.translate(centerX,centerY);
    ctx.rotate(radians);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo (size * Math.cos(0), size * Math.sin(0));          
    for (var i = 1; i <= sideCount;i += 1) {
        ctx.lineTo (size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount), size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount));
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.rotate(-radians);
    ctx.translate(-centerX,-centerY);    }
```

```css
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried adding bits of your `drawPolygon()` function. I read somewhere that canvases use east as 0 degrees. When I added this code to convert my degrees to canvas degrees the triangle stopped drawing: `Orientation = Orientation - 90; if (Orientation < 0) { Orientation = 360 + Orientation; }`. When I don't add that code it draws successfully.

Comment: @Jared. Correct! By default zero degrees points "east". In the `drawPolygon` function, if you want `rotationDegrees` to point north when set to zero, you can `rotationDegrees-=90;` **before** `var radians...`.  BTW, You don't have to normalize the angle by adding 360 degrees ... javascript will normalize values outside 0-360 into that range.  Note: I have edited my demo to include moving the center of the triangle to [centerX,centerY] inside `drawPolygon`. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I add `rotationDegrees -= 90` to my code no polygons are drawn. This is my own (pretty verbose) function with modifications based on your function: http://pastebin.com/htbNrWNg Without the -90 code it works fine. `Orientation` is usually `0` and after `-=90` it becomes `-90` which is expected.

Comment: Do I need to add `context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);` somewhere?

Comment: Oops? Your pastbin was removed when I went to look at it. Perhaps start with the revised `drawPolygon` code in my answer. It seems to have all the options that you need. `setTransform` is not needed because the centerX, centerY sent into drawPolygon will position the triangle's centerpoint on the canvas.

Comment: I found what was going wrong. I was reversing the rotation after the reverse translation not before it. I swapped them around and it's drawing correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Please look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyanGhatak/404okos3/3/). You can send the orientation as an optional paramenter. It accepts 'east', 'west', 'north','south'. Please validate.

`
function drawTriangle(PosX, PosY, SideLength, Orientation) {

```
if (!Orientation) {
   Orientation = 'east';
}

context.beginPath();

var sides = 3;

var a = ((Math.PI * 2) / sides);
// the components have negative contributions
if (Orientation === 'west' || Orientation === 'north') {
    SideLength *= -1;
}

if (Orientation === 'east' || Orientation === 'west') {
    context.moveTo(PosX + SideLength, PosY);

    for (var i = 1; i < sides + 1; i++) {
        context.lineTo(PosX + SideLength * Math.cos(a*i), PosY + SideLength * Math.sin(a*i));
    }
}
else if (Orientation === 'south' || Orientation === 'north') {
    context.moveTo(PosY, PosX + SideLength);

    for (var i = 1; i < sides + 1; i++) {
        context.lineTo(PosY + SideLength * Math.sin(a*i), PosX + SideLength * Math.cos(a*i));
    }
}
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

}`

Comment: When I set the orientation to north or south, the triangle is drawn very far away. When it is east or west it looks as expected. Do you know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

To rotate only the particular shape but not the entire canvas - you should rotate manually every point it consists of then draw it with rotated points.

check this example I created, it does not use any `canvas API` functions for rotation or translation also draws any regular polygon.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("cnv").getContext('2d');
var id = 0;

var Point2d = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
}

Point2d.prototype.set = function(x, y) { 
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

Point2d.prototype.translate = function(p) { 
  this.x += p.x;
  this.y += p.y;
  return this;
};

//rotation around origin
Point2d.prototype.rotate = function(phi) {
  this.set(
    this.x*Math.cos(phi) - this.y*Math.sin(phi),
    this.x*Math.sin(phi) + this.y*Math.cos(phi)
  );
  return this;
};


function getRegularPolygonPoints(center, numSides, sideLength) {
  var points = [];
  var alpha = 2*Math.PI / numSides;  
  for (var i = 0; i < numSides; i++) {
    points.push(new Point2d( 
      center.x + sideLength*Math.cos(alpha*i),
      center.y + sideLength*Math.sin(alpha*i))
    )
  }  
  return points;
}


function drawPolygon(points) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y); 
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);//  close the shape
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#899";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function rotatePolygon(polygonPoints, phi, pointAround) {
  var pointAroundInv= new Point2d(-pointAround.x, -pointAround.y);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < polygonPoints.length; i++) {
    polygonPoints[i].translate(pointAroundInv);//  translate to origin
    polygonPoints[i].rotate(phi);//  rotate
    polygonPoints[i].translate(pointAround);// translate back to it's original position
  }
}

var center = new Point2d(250, 120);
var regPolPoints = getRegularPolygonPoints(center, 3, 50);
var currentFrame = (new Date).getTime();
var lastFrame = currentFrame;
var dt = 0;

var render = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  currentFrame = (new Date).getTime();
  dt = currentFrame - lastFrame;
  lastFrame = currentFrame; 
  
  rotatePolygon(regPolPoints, -dt/600, center);
  drawPolygon(regPolPoints);
  id = requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

id = requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: [erfect answer, exactly what I was looking for.. should be the accepted one

Answer (score 3):

The math here is very simple. We are drawing lines between the equiangular points taken from the circle with radius *radius* (see argument below). Also, we should keep in mind that *SideLength* is not real side length of the polygon. I've simplified initial code and added figure rotation feature. The resulting function together with example is presented below:

```js
        /* here, radius means the radius of circle, inside of which polygon is drawn */
        function drawTriangle(context, PosX, PosY, radius, rotate) {
            context.beginPath();

            /* number of vertices for polygon */
            var sides = 3;
            /* angle between vertices of polygon */
            var a = ((Math.PI * 2) / sides);

            for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
                context.lineTo(PosX + radius * Math.cos(a*i+rotate), PosY + radius * Math.sin(a*i+rotate));
            }

            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();

            return true;
        }

        var canvas = document.getElementById("demo")
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var PosX = 50;
            var PosY = 50;
            var radius = 40;
            drawTriangle(ctx, PosX, PosY, radius, Math.PI / 4);
        }
```

```css
canvas#demo
{
  border: thin solid green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="demo" width="200" height="200">
    This browser or document mode doesn't support canvas
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

To rotate the triangle

```
drawTriangle(PosX, PosY, SideLength, Orientation) {
    context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,PosX,PosY); // Set position
    context.rotate(Orientation);  // set rotation in radians
    context.beginPath();
    var sides = 3;
    var a = ((Math.PI * 2) / sides);
    context.moveTo(SideLength,0);

    for (var i = 1; i < sides + 1; i++) {
        context.lineTo(SideLength * Math.cos(a*i), SideLength * Math.sin(a*i));
    }

    context.closePath();
    context.fill()
    context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);// reset the transform

    return true;
}
```